# Is there an API to determine the last time a user used the Google Drive Desktop application?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

I want to find out when a user last used the Google Drive on the Desktop. Is there an API that can show me this? Either an individually-authorized API, or a Google Apps Domain-wide API? I can determine when a user last logged in using the Admin SDK Reports API, but it doesn't seem to show what application was used; similarly I can determine if an OAuth token was granted, but does this log every time that token was used?

Comment: According to [Monitor usage and security with reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6000239?hl=en), Admin console reports and logs make it easy to examine potential security risks, measure user collaboration, track who signs in and when, analyze administrator activity, and much more.It also can access all the data from the Security, Apps Usage Activity, and Highlights pages in a single master report. Also check the [Admin console reports and logs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4589321), it provide some data regarding different APIs. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't allow me to see when a token was used for a login (only when it was authorized), nor does it provide an API.